# How to format a query to return data dating no later than 90 days on a .aspx web page with DropDownList control parameter?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement, drop-down-menu

The variable **@status** takes three values, C, N, V on one web page if selected to call the query below.
How to format the query to return data dating no later than 90 days in the query below in order to return if selected, item with a date (entry_date) no later than 90 days for only `@status = 'C'`, but for other statuses V and N to return data without any date constrain?

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"  

 SelectCommand="SELECT W.order_id, w.entry_date, w.s_num, w.prot_num, w.i_num, w.phm_num, w.status, w.Comments, w.UName, w.prStatus, S.S_Name, 
                  ISNULL(p.Phm_fname, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(p.Phm_lname, ' ') AS 'PhmName', ISNULL(S.PHM_CITY, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(S.PHM_STATE, ' ') AS 'Phm_city'
FROM         Web_Ship AS w INNER JOIN
                  Phm_of_rcrd AS p ON p.phm_num = w.phm_num INNER JOIN
                  Stdy_Site AS S ON w.s_num = S.S_Num
WHERE     (w.status = @status)
ORDER BY w.order_id DESC"
            <SelectParameters>
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="StatusDropDownList" Name="Status" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type="Char" />
            </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an IF statement but a slightly modified Where clause as below:

```
WHERE     (w.status = @status)
AND (
     (@status = 'C' AND entry_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -90 , GETDATE()))
     OR 
     (@status IN ('V','N'))
    )
```

Comment: @M. Ali, thank you that resolves the issue. It worked fine.

Comment: I agree with the solution @M.Ali provided but my approach would have been slightly different. I would have done this: `WHERE (w.status = @status) AND (CASE @status WHEN 'C' THEN DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), w.entry_date) ELSE 0 END) >= 90 `

Comment: @Zac, thanks again for this alternative. This works fine  as well. I just learned two ways of doing one thing.

Comment: @ZacBraddy your suggested method may bring the same results back but it will perform poorly as it is not a Sargable expression, `DATEDIFF` function will ignore any indexes defined on the `Entry_Date` column. hence it will perform poorly as compare to my suggested method which is sargable and will make use of any indexes defined on the `Entry_Date` column.

Comment: @M.Ali Thank you for the knowledge :)

Comment: @M.Ali, thank for the explanation on the performance issue. This helps a lot.